# Metal texture format bgra8Unorm_srgb non-writable on Metal Family 2 GPU

Tags: gpu, shader, intel, metal

I'm passing a texture with `MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm_srgb` to a compute shader, which has a `texture2d<float, access::write>` for this texture. I am getting the following error:

- `validateComputeFunctionArguments:818: failed assertion Compute Function(rescaleTexture): Non-writeable texture format MTLPixelFormat.BGRA8Unorm_sRGB is being bound at index 1 to a shader argument with write access enabled.`

I've a "**Metal Family 2 GPU**" (Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640, Metal family: Supported, Metal GPUFamily macOS 2), and according to the Apple documentation, a texture with `MTLPixelFormat.BGRA8Unorm_sRGB` pixel format should be writable.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is (a part of) the code I use to create the texture(s):

```
let desc = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(
    pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm_srgb,
    width: outputTextureWidth,
    height: outputTextureHeight,
    mipmapped: false)
desc.usage = [.shaderRead, .shaderWrite]
let tex = device.makeTexture(descriptor: desc)
```

Here is (a part of) shader code:

```
kernel void
rescaleTexture(texture2d<float, access::sample> source [[texture(0)]],
               texture2d<float, access::write> target [[texture(1)]],
               uint2 id [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if (id.x >= target.get_width() || id.y >= target.get_height()) {
        return;
    }

    const float u = (float)id.x / (target.get_width () - 1);
    const float v = (float)id.y / (target.get_height () - 1);

    target.write (source.sample (sampler_linear_no_mipmap, float2 (u, v)), id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [The Metal Feature Set Tables](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf):
**BGRA8Unorm_sRGB** texture format of **MTLGPUFamilyMac2** processors, have the following capabilities:

- Filter
- Color
- MSAA
- Resolve
- Blend

This mean the texture with format of **BGRA8Unorm_sRGB** can not be written to by a function on your device.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the docs for MTLGPUFamilyApple2 instead of MTLGPUFamilyMac2!